# Postgresql upper limit of a calculated field

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns, calculated-field

is there a way to set an upper limit to a calculation (calculated field) which is already in a CASE clause? I'm calculating percentages and, obviously, don't want the highest value exceed '100'.

If it wasn't in a CASE clause already, I'd create something like 'case when calculation > 100.0 then 100 else calculation end as needed_percent' but I can't do it now..

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think using [least](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) function will be the best option.

```
select least((case when ...), 100) from ...
```

Comment: @NickBarnes sure it was mistake, I was thinking about least. updated answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set an upper limit on a calculated field by creating an outer query. Check out my example below. The inner query will be the query that you have currently. Then just create an outer query on it and use a WHERE clause to limit it to <= 1.

```
SELECT 
z.id,
z.name,
z.percent

FROM(

SELECT
id,
name,
CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN sales/SUM(sales) ELSE NULL END AS percent

FROM 
users_table

) AS z

WHERE z.percent <= 1
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Using 'least' did the trick :). I'll take a look at all the suggestions, one never knows when it comes handy.